# Jenkins shared library; Refer to static resource (xml) file when executing maven commands

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

We are currently in the process of setting up a Jenkins shared library to be used for several Java projects. Our file `vars/utils.groovy` contains the following (simplified) snippet:

```
def mvn(String mvnCommand) {
    // withCredentials(userVarEtc=USER, pwVarEtc=PASS, etc, etc) {
      sh "mvn ${mvnCommand} -Duser${USER} -Dpass${PASS} --settings maven_settings.xml"
    // }
}
```

Although above snippet works fine, it requires all Java projects to keep the exact same `maven_settings.xml` template file in the root of the project. To prevent duplication we would like to add the `maven_settings.xml` file in the shared library and refer to its shared library path in the groovy method above. Would anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two possible solutions.

**Solution 1**

1. Keep the file `maven_settings.xml` in the `resources` directory.

   ```
   shared-library-repository
   +--resources/maven_settings.xml
   +--vars/utils.groovy
   ```
2. In your shared library method, read this file and write to workspace before calling the maven commands.

   ```
   def mvn(String mvnCommand) {
     def myMavenSettings = libraryResource 'maven_settings.xml'
     writeFile file: 'maven_settings.xml', text: myMavenSettings
     withCredentials(userVarEtc=USER, pwVarEtc=PASS, etc, etc) {
       sh "mvn ${mvnCommand} -Duser${USER} -Dpass${PASS} --settings $WORKSPACE/maven_settings.xml"
     }
   }
   ```

**Solution 2**

1. Install the [Config File Provider](https://plugins.jenkins.io/config-file-provider/) plugin.
2. Go to **Manage Jenkins** > **Managed files** > **Add a new Config**.
3. Click **Maven settings.xml** and then **Submit**.
4. Type the name and paste the content in the designated fields.
5. Rename or copy the file ID and then click **Save**.
6. In you shared library method, invoke the plugin step to run maven commands.

   ```
   def mvn(String mvnCommand) {
     configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '<file_ID>', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
       withCredentials(userVarEtc=USER, pwVarEtc=PASS, etc, etc) {
         sh "mvn ${mvnCommand} -Duser${USER} -Dpass${PASS} --settings $MAVEN_SETTINGS"
       }
     }
   }
   ```